# backbone.js sortBy cid

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, collections

I'm using backbone.js and trying to sort a collection by cid. How do I sort by cid??

I can sort it by attribute like 'name':

> this.collection.sortBy("name")

this works.

But when I try to do this:

> this.collection.sortBy("cid")

it returns a collection but its not sorted, its just the same as before.

and I tried this:

> this.collection.sortBy(cid)

this returns an error obviously.

Any help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sortBy` sorts based on either an attribute on the model, or an iterator. Since `cid` is directly on the model and not an attribute, you need to use the iterator.

```
this.collection.sortBy(function(model){
  return model.cid;
});
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes when it lets me :P